# Solr new Core from UI

Tags: windows, solr, cygwin, nutch

I'm trying to create a new Core with Solr 5.3. I have no experience working with Solr until a few days ago. I think I need this broken down Barney style. I've been through the system doc, wiki's, YouTube, and random discussion boards. The information I've found is either not current or not what I'm seeing from my UI. I've now wasted five hours trying to get this to work. I'm out of options. I'm about ready to drop this project and start from scratch. I'm completely exasperated and throwing myself to the mercy of my betters. Can anyone just show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the following steps for adding a `core` using solr admin UI.

1. Start the solr server using `~/solr-5.2.0/bin/solr start`. This will start the solr on 8983 port.
2. Now go to `solr` directory. `cd ~/solr-5.2.0/server/solr`.
3. Create a new folder, which will contain the solr core configuration. `mkdir newCore`.
4. Now create a `conf` directory in side the `newCore` and copy your `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` along with other necessary files.
5. Go to **Solr Admin UI**, `Core Admims` section. Specify the **core name**, as per your requirement and `newCore` (name of the directory which we have created) in the `instanceDir` field. Click the `Add Core` button.

Comment: I saw something like this in a tutorial online. Where do I get the schema and solrconfig xml files? Do I have to write them myself? I probably can. I have a good grasp of xml. Doing it the way I specified below via the cmd line will automatically create those files though. Thoughts? Thank you for your response, it really does elucidate things!

Comment: you can copy them initially from `configsets` provided with solr setup and edit them as per your requirement.

Comment: does it solve your problem? Are you able to create `core` from UI?

Comment: It did work with just one tweak. I couldn't just add the schema and solrconfig from from configsets. I had to copy/paste the entire conf directory from configsets/basic_configs and use that. Otherwise worked like a champ!

Comment: Yes. Because the default `schema.xml` reference to many other files. The same I mentioned in `point 4`. above.

Answer (score 2):

I found a tutorial here: [apache-solr-tutorial-beginners](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/apache-solr-tutorial-beginners/)

I followed the exact instructions the author gives for creating a new core via the command line from `solar-5.3.0/bin`:

```
solr create -c jcg -d basic_configs
```

`jcg` then appeared in my Solr UI.

I went back and tried this same thing with my Project specs and it worked! I still have no idea how to do this from the UI but at least I can move forward an inch!